# A binomial coefficient identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

i'm unable to prove the following : $\forall n$ integer $\geq 3$,

$ \displaystyle \displaystyle \sum_{s=1}^n \sum_{j=n-s+1}^n \displaystyle \frac{  (\binom n j )^2 \binom {n+j} n }{s-n+j} ( \displaystyle \sum_{t=1}^n \displaystyle \frac{1}{j+t} +2 \displaystyle \sum_{t=0,t \neq j}^n \displaystyle \frac{1}{t-j}) $
$  =\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^n  \displaystyle \sum_{r=s+1}^n \displaystyle \frac{   \binom n r   \binom n s  (-1)^{r+s} }{r-s} {\Big{(}}   \binom {n+r} n +  \binom {n+s} n {\Big{)}} \displaystyle \sum_{t=s+1}^r \frac{1}{t}  $

Any help? Is that a new result?

Comment: Is there a q-analogue of this?

Comment: i don't know (i have found this )  making computation

Comment: $ \displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^n   \binom n s (-1)^s \binom {s+n} n   \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \displaystyle \frac{1}{t+s+1}=0$

Comment: for all value $ 0 \leq t \leq n-1$ ( the explain of  that is simple we can use  orthonalite legendre polynom $P_n to x^t$ and expand term inside integral $ P_n*x^t $ and integrate term by term)

Comment: this may be can usefll at the second member to proof the identity above